Random constraints on array of structure elements
typedef enum {HEARTS, DIAMONDS, CLUBS, SPADES} Suit;
typedef enum {TWO = 2, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING, ACE} Value;
typedef struct{
    randc Suit card_type;
    rand Value card_value;  
}card;

class Deck;
  rand card cards_drawn[2:0];
  
  // Constraint to ensure that the cards are in increasing order
  constraint cards_order_and_suit {
    foreach (cards_drawn[i]) {
      if (i > 0) {
        cards_drawn[i].card_value > cards_drawn[i-1].card_value;
      }
    }        
  }
        
endclass

module test;
  initial repeat(5) begin
    automatic Deck deck = new();
    assert(deck.randomize()) else $display("Failed to draw three cards");
    foreach (deck.cards_drawn[i]) begin
      $display("Card %0d: Suit = %s, Value = %s", i, deck.cards_drawn[i].card_type.name(), deck.cards_drawn[i].card_value.name());
      end
  end
endmodule

I want unique suits for the three cards drawn.  I've tried using randc on the enum type suit variable, but it doesn't seem to work.  I am not getting any simulation errors as well with three simulators.
The code works fine if I specify separate constraint for the uniqueness of card suit, but I wanted to explore if we can do something like this mentioning randc inside a structure on an enum type variable.

randc only works on subsequent calls to randomize, not within a single call to randomize.  For example, the first time you call randomize, randc has no effect on the array of card objects.  It will randomly select a Suit for each element of the array with no constraints.  You may get 2 or more cards of the same suit in the array.  The 2nd time you call randomize, it will remember the random values from the first call.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2023, section 18.4 Random variables for a thorough discussion.
Just declare card_type as rand.  One straightforward way to get unique suits is to use the unique keyword inside the constraint block.  Yes, you need to repeat similar code 3 times, but it's only 3 lines of code:
typedef struct{
    rand  Suit card_type;
    rand Value card_value;  
} card;

class Deck;
  rand card cards_drawn [3];
  
  // Constraint to ensure that the cards are in increasing order
  constraint cards_order_and_suit {
    foreach (cards_drawn[i]) {
      if (i > 0) {
        cards_drawn[i].card_value > cards_drawn[i-1].card_value;
      }
    }        
    unique {
        cards_drawn[0].card_type,
        cards_drawn[1].card_type,
        cards_drawn[2].card_type
    };
  }     
endclass

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2023, section 18.5.4 Uniqueness constraints
